# d3: what is the self as in d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have seen statements like below in many D3 examples. However, I can't find out what it means. In particular, I don't know what this `self` variable refers to. Additionally, does this manifest some sort of D3 magic/convention or is it just an ad-hoc thing? Thank you very much.

```
d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");
```

BTW, [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063570) is the example where I copied the above statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`self`: if not redefined (typically as copy of `this`) than it is `window` object which always points to `window`. So they can be used interchangeably.

`window.frameElement`: Returns the element (such as <iframe> or <object>) in which the window is embedded, or null if the window is top-level.

See [Window.frameElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.frameElement)

Answer (score 3):

On [this](http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426) example I found the following comment:

```
// Hack to make this example display correctly in an iframe on bl.ocks.org
```